# Looking for a workaround to a GNU linker bug

Tags: linux, ld

Since a while (probably 12 years), the GNU linker includes support for linker map files for versioned shared libraries as introduced by Sun in 1993.

Unfortunately, the GNU linker rejects correct linker map files, but likes to see similar map files in reversed order.

A correct linker map file looks like:

```
SCHILY_3 {
global:
    function5;
    function6;
local:
     *;
} SCHILY_2;

SCHILY_2 {
global:
    function3;
    function4;
local:
     *;
} SCHILY_1;

SCHILY_1 {
global:
    function1;
    function2;
local:
     *;
};
```

The GNU linker however seems to like it this way:

```
SCHILY_1 {
global:
    function1;
    function2;
local:
     *;
};

SCHILY_2 {
global:
    function3;
    function4;
local:
     *;
} SCHILY_1;

SCHILY_3 {
global:
    function5;
    function6;
local:
     *;
} SCHILY_2;
```

Does someone know a way to automatically convert the first correct form into the second for using UNIX/LINUX on-board programs?

Comment: To be fair, while the GNU linker is unhappy with the first form, I believe *every* linker (that supports version scripts) should be happy with the second form... So maybe just consider converting it and use what you call the "reverse" form for all the linkers on all platforms? If that's the case, then a one-time manual conversion should be fine. If the example is simple as you describe, then just splitting in blocks on newline and printing them back in reverse order should be enough?

Comment: Given the under-specification and non-standard nature of linker scripts, I'm not completely surprised (or at all disappointed) that the GNU linker developers decided to only support references to already defined names and break on forward references... I mean, there's really no reason why you *need* forward references here (unlike in C source where they're absolutely needed in some cases.)

Comment: If you ever like to use the GNU linker to e.g. link a Solaris ARM port because the UNIX linker has not yet been ported to support ARM, you definitely don't like to manually convert thousands of linker map files.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the right basic idea taken from a friend, I have been able to find a solution for a filter:

```
| sed 's/^SCHILY/+SCHILY/' | tr '\012' '@' | tr '+' '\012' | sort -t. -n -k1 -k2 -k3 |  tr '@' '\012'
```

This first `sed`  makes the block start unique, the first `tr` removes newlines, the second `tr` makes block starts separate lines, the `sort` command creates the needed order and the final `tr` command restores all newlines.

The `sed` command is a bit complex as it needs to deal with up to three levels of ordering.